# Confusion around function call resolution

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, function-calls, overload-resolution, argument-dependent-lookup

This question is inspired by [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030925/why-move-swap-impl-in-boostswap-to-a-separate-namespace). Consider the code:

```
namespace ns {
  template <typename T>
  void swap(T& a, T& b) {
    using namespace std;
    swap(a, b);
  }
}
```

After some test with GCC, I found that `swap(a, b);` resolves to
1) `std::swap` if `T` has overloaded `std::swap` (e.g., standard container types)
2) `ns::swap` otherwise, leading to infinite recursion.
So, it seems that the compiler will first try to find a match in the namespace `ns`. If a match is found, the search ends. But this is not the case when ADL comes in, in which case, `std::swap` is found anyway. The resolution process seems to be complicated.

I want to know the details of what is going on under the hood in the process of resolving the function call `swap(a, b)` in the above context. Reference to the standard would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that using-directives such as `using namespace std;` behave a very peculiar behaviour; they're not using-declarations such as `using std::swap`.

Comment: @dyp Just had a deep feeling about that :-)

Comment: As far as I can tell, this using-directive won't do anything. It makes names of namespace `std` visible as if they're declared in the global namespace here, but the name `swap` in the global namespace is hidden for pure unqualified lookup inside `ns::swap` because the namespace `ns` already contains a member of the name `swap`.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, if you change it to using std::swap, we'll get compilation error since compiler will see both std::swap and ns::swap.

Comment: @AntonFrolov There are two mechanisms for name lookup involved here: pure unqualified lookup and argument-dependent lookup. Pure unqualified lookup will stop in the next enclosing scope where it finds the name. With `using std::swap;`, we tell it to stop at block scope - `ns::swap` will not be found, it is a member of the enclosing namespace scope. Argument-dependent lookup on the other hand searches all scopes associated with the types of the arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code in the OP is *equivalent* to this:

```
using std::swap; // only for name lookup inside ns::swap

namespace ns {
  template <typename T>
  void swap(T& a, T& b) {
    swap(a, b);
  }
}
```

Why? Because *using-directives* like `using namespace std;` have a very peculiar behaviour C++14 [namespace.udir]p2:

> A *using-directive* specifies that the names in the nominated namespace
>   can be used in the scope in which the *using-directive* appears after
>   the *using-directive*. During unqualified name lookup, the names
>   appear as if they were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace
>   which contains both the *using-directive* and the nominated namespace.

The nearest enclosing namespace that contains both namespace `std` and the block scope of function `ns::swap` is the global namespace.

*Using-declarations* such as `using std::swap;` on the other hand really introduce names into the scope in which they appear, not in some enclosing scope.

---

The lookup of a function call expression such as `swap(a, b)` is called *unqualified lookup*. The identifier `swap` has not been qualified with any namespace or class name, as opposed to `ns::swap`, which has been qualified via `ns::`. Unqualified lookup for potential names of functions consists of two parts: pure unqualified lookup and argument-dependent lookup.

Pure unqualified lookup stops at the nearest enclosing scope that contains the name. In the OP's example, as illustrated by the equivalent transformation shown above, the nearest scope that contains a declaration of the name `swap` is the namespace `ns`. The global scope will not be searched, `std::swap` will not be found via pure unqualified lookup.

Argument-dependent lookup searches all scopes (here: only namespaces and classes) associated with the argument types. For class types, the namespace in which the class has been declared in is an associated scope. Types of the C++ Standard Library such as `std::vector<int>` are associated with namespace `std`, hence `std::swap` can be found via argument-dependent lookup for the expression `swap(a, b)` if `T` is a C++ Standard Library type. Similarly, your own class types allow finding a `swap` function in the namespaces they have been declared in:

```
namespace N2 {
    class MyClass {};
    void swap(MyClass&, MyClass&);
}
```

Therefore, if argument-dependent lookup does not find a better match than pure unqualified lookup, you'll end up calling `ns::swap` recursively.

---

The idea behind calling `swap` unqualified, that is, `swap(a, b)` instead of `std::swap(a, b)` is that functions found via argument-dependent lookup are assumed to be more specialized than `std::swap`. Specializing a function template such as `std::swap` for your own class template type is impossible (since partial function template specializations are forbidden), and you may not add custom overloads to namespace `std`. The generic version of `std::swap` is implemented typically as follows:

```
template<typename T>
void swap(T& a, T& b)
{
    T tmp( move(a) );
    a = move(b);
    b = move(tmp);
}
```

This requires a move-construction plus two move-assignments, which might even fall back to copies. Therefore, you can provide a *specialized swap function* for your own types in the namespaces associated with those types. Your specialized version can make use of certain properties of, or private access to, your own types.

Comment: You were both faster and more detailed, +1.

Comment: @Angew I probably just started earlier ;)

Comment: I just thought overloading `std::swap` for custom types is standard practice.

Comment: @Lingxi Programs may not add definitions or declarations to the `std` namespace "unless otherwise specified" [namespace.std]p1. There is no such exception for `std::swap`. The common practice I know of is to define `swap` as a non-member friend function, possibly defined inside the class body. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/5695855/ Types defined by the C++ Standard Library do overload `std::swap`, but they're in the unique position of being part of the Standard - and `std` is the namespace they're associated with (so this follows the aforementioned common practice).

Answer (score 2):

The most important piece of the standard is 7.3.4/2 (quoting C++14 n4140, emphasis mine):

> A *using-directive* specifies that the names in the nominated namespace can be used in the scope in which the
>   *using-directive* appears after the *using-directive.* **During unqualified name lookup (3.4.1), the names appear
>   as if they were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace which contains both the *using-directive* and the
>   nominated namespace.**

The *using-directive* is located inside a function in `:: ns`, and nominates `:: std`. This means that for the purpose of unqualified name lookup, the effect of this *using-directive* is that names in `::std` behave as if they were declared in `::`. Particularly, *not* as if they were in `::ns`.

Because the unqualified name lookup begins inside a function in `::ns`, it will search `::ns` before looking into `::`. And it finds `::ns::swap`, so it ends there, without examining `::`, where it would find `::std::swap` brought in by the *using-directive.*